# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function - I am lost

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore

```
INDEX.JS FILE

    import { compose, createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
    import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
    import firebase from '../Firebase/Firebase';
    import { reactReduxFirebase, getFirebase } from 'react-redux-firebase';
    import { reduxFirestore, getFirestore } from 'redux-firestore';

    import rootReducer from './reducers';

    // react-redux-firebase config
    const rrfConfig = {
      userProfile: 'users',
      useFirestoreForProfile: true, // Firestore for Profile instead of Realtime DB
    };

    const composeEnhancers =
      process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
        ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose
        : compose;

    const store = createStore(
      rootReducer,
      composeEnhancers(
        reactReduxFirebase(firebase, rrfConfig),
        reduxFirestore(firebase),
        applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({ getFirebase, getFirestore }))
      )
    );
    export default store;
```

I believe my formatting is correct, however, I am lost. Can someone help, please? Below are my two files in my reducers folder.Please feel free to ask any questions you may have, and I will do my best to answer them. I am seriously stuck.

---

```
REDUCERS -> AUTHREDUCER.JS

const initialState = {

}

export default(state = initialState, action) => {
    return'dhdhdhd';
};
```

---

```
REDUCERS -> INDEX.JS

import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import { firebaseReducer } from 'react-redux-firebase';

import authReducer from './authReducer';

export default combineReducers({
    auth: authReducer,
    firebase: firebaseReducer,
});`enter code here`
```

When running NPM start, I return this error :

> "TypeError: Object(...) is not a function" at const store = createStore( .

Comment: can we see your `reducers` file?

Comment: `const initialState = {

}

export default(state = initialState, action) => {
    return'dhdhdhd';
};`

Comment: `import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import { firebaseReducer } from 'react-redux-firebase';

import authReducer from './authReducer';

export default combineReducers({
    auth: authReducer,
    firebase: firebaseReducer,
});`

Comment: I can't tell from your two above comments which files these are. Can you please edit your question and add the code with the filenames please

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have made the edits and they are reflected above.

Answer (score 0):

checkout https://redux.js.org/api/createstore, I believe 2nd argument should be initial state

```
const initialState = {} // the initial value for your state

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState, // 2nd argument of createStore is initial state
  composeEnhancers(
    ...
  )
);
```

**UPDATED:**

checkout http://docs.react-redux-firebase.com/history/v3.0.0/docs/v3-migration-guide.html#remove-store-enhancer as they have deprecated the enhancer for react-redux-firebase

so

- Remove the reactReduxFirebase from the enhancers
- Use the `ReactReduxFirebaseProvider`

```js
const rrfProps = {
  ...
};
const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ReactReduxFirebaseProvider {...rrfConfig}>
      ...
    </ReactReduxFirebaseProvider>
  </Provider>
);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work. I added the const initialState = {} and added the initialState under rootReducer :(

Comment: and you're still getting the same error `TypeError: Object(...) is not a function`?

Comment: Yes sir! Unfortunately :/

Comment: I suspect, one of the function inside composeEnhancer returns undefined.. could you console.log `reactReduxFirebase(firebase, rrfConfig)` and `reduxFirestore(firebase)` and make sure they return function types

Comment: I added `console.log(reactReduxFirebase(firebase, rrfConfig))
console.log(reduxFirestore(firebase))` at the bottom under `);` however, nothing was logged to the console. Am I formatting this incorrectly?

Comment: that should log something, not sure why you're not seeing anything.. can u try removing the line `reactReduxFirebase(firebase, rrfConfig)` and check if the error would go away.

Comment: Yes, that worked. Will this ruin my connection to firebase though?

Comment: you know what, I think I know what's happening. you've installed v3 of react-redux-firebase while the way you're using it is for older version of the module.. try to follow the migration guide here. http://docs.react-redux-firebase.com/history/v3.0.0/docs/v3-migration-guide.html#remove-store-enhancer

Comment: Ah, that would make sense. In my package.json file, I do have version 3 installed. Okay, I will attempt at this and get back to you on this thread. You're awesome :)